# How to have custom video media/stream sink request RGB32 frames in media foundation?

Tags: windows, opengl, rgb, mp4, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to make a custom media sink for video playback in an OpenGL application (without the various WGL_NV_DX_INTEROP, as I am not sure if all my target devices support this).

What I have done so far is to write a custom stream sink that accepts **RGB32** samples and set up playback with a media session, however i encountered a problem with initial testing of playing an mp4 file:

- one (or more) of the **MFT**s in the generated topology keep failing with an error code **MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT**, therefore my stream sink never receives samples
- After a few samples have been requested, the media session receives the event **MF_E_ATTRIBUTENOTFOUND**, but I still don't know where it is coming from

If, however, I configure the stream sink to receive **NV12** samples, everything seems to work fine.

My best guess is the color converter MFT generated by the TopologyLoader needs some more configuration, but I don't know how to do that, considering that I need to keep this entire process indipendent from the original file types.

Comment: Can you provide the mp4 file ? Can you explain also how TopologyLoader is setup ?

Comment: It has the same effect on variety of mp4 files. The topology is set up by connecting the MediaSource to the MediaSink and then resolved through the default topology loader

Comment: ok, can you test with this file : big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb.mp4, so i can also test ?

Comment: I moved towards using the SourceReader, so I’m not in a position to test anymore. But I still have the code, I will test either tomorrow or the day after. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

I've made a minimal test case, that demonstrate the use of a custom video renderer with a classical Media Session.

I use big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb.mp4, and i don't see any problems using RGB32 format.

Sample code here : https://github.com/mofo7777/Stackoverflow under MinimalSinkRenderer.

**EDIT**

Your program works well with big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb.mp4. I think that your mp4 file is the problem. Share it, if you can.

I just made a few changes :

You Stop on MESessionEnded, and you Close on MESessionStopped.

```
case MediaEventType.MESessionEnded:
    Debug.WriteLine("MediaSession:SesssionEndedEvent");
    hr = mediaSession.Stop();
    break;
case MediaEventType.MESessionClosed:
    Debug.WriteLine("MediaSession:SessionClosedEvent");
    receiveSessionEvent = false;
    break;
case MediaEventType.MESessionStopped:
    Debug.WriteLine("MediaSession:SesssionStoppedEvent");
    hr = mediaSession.Close();
    break;
default:
    Debug.WriteLine("MediaSession:Event: " + eventType);
    break;
```

Adding this to wait for the sound, and to check sample is ok :

```
internal HResult ProcessSample(IMFSample s)
{
    //Debug.WriteLine("Received sample!");

    CurrentFrame++;

    if (s != null)
    {
        long llSampleTime = 0;
        HResult hr = s.GetSampleTime(out llSampleTime);

        if (hr == HResult.S_OK && ((CurrentFrame % 50) == 0))
        {
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(llSampleTime / (10000000 / 1000));
            Debug.WriteLine("Frame {0} : {1}", CurrentFrame.ToString(), ts.ToString());
        }

        // Do not call SafeRelease here, it is done by the caller, it is a parameter
        //SafeRelease(s);
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(26);

    return HResult.S_OK;
}
```

In

```
public HResult SetPresentationClock(IMFPresentationClock pPresentationClock)
```

adding

```
SafeRelease(PresentationClock);
```

before

```
if (pPresentationClock != null)
    PresentationClock = pPresentationClock;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, but I have been rather busy.
I have been taking a quick look at your code and there doesn't seem to be any difference logic wise (I am using C#). I'll try and reimplement mine using yours as a bse

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your example in C#, and failed. Running MFTrace I get the exact error I got last time (**MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT**). Repository available [here](https://github.com/jstefanelli/MFTestStackOverflow)

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your help! I have implemented the chagnes you suggested (aside from the ones in the sample, as I just need to get one and then do some elaboration), and I didn't have any luck. Unfortunately, I cannot send you the file for copyright reasons, but I have noticed the same problem on a variety of viedos. I'm starting to think that it might be related to my system. I also don't have your Big Buck Bunny video, could you please share that, so I can test it with my system?

Comment: Very weird! With that video it works fine. I'll try to get more precise information about the format and codec of the video that I want to play and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I ran ffprobe and I found some very slight differences on the video codec format. Still have no idea why it works fine with the SourceReader though... you can check the ffprobe output [here](https://gist.github.com/jstefanelli/57caf514c167db5a3564e3706b70853e)